# When dry hopping, do you wait for clearing before bottling?

Tags: bottling, dry-hop, beginner

I'm still a beginner, this forum has helped me a great deal. I made an IPA, which cleared very well in the primary.  It was transferred to a secondary for dry hopping, adding a muslin bag with 1 oz Citra pellet hops, it's been a week and I pulled the hops, satisfied with the flavor.  I got some sediment in the bottom of the carboy, but the beer isn't as clear as it was following the primary. Should I wait to bottle or just go with it as is, carefully racking to a bottling bucket? Will any carry over sediment settle in the bottle?  Thanks for the help and patience.

Comment: Don't stick your racking cane all into the trub at the bottom of your bucket.  Slowly and steadily lower it along the beer line while siphoning to prevent stirring any of the trub back into suspension.

Answer (score 2):

I would bottle now and not bother waiting.

The beer will clear in the bottles while you are waiting for the carbonation process to take place.

I bottled some dry hopped beer that you could not see through and when it was ready to drink(just under two weeks) it was crystal clear.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Dry hopping can induce some haze from hop polyphenols/hop tannins. Although, I'd be surprised if 1oz would really contribute to much haze.  Sounds like you are ready to bottle.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

These are all good answers.  I always try to move by carboy to the spot where I'm going to siphon from for a few hours (ideally 12 hours ore more) before I do siphon so as much can settle as possible.  Assuming your bottle conditioning these you won't be pouring out the last drops, so what ever settles in the bottle will stay in the bottle.

Cheers

Comment: All comments were great, these really help fill in the blanks that we beginners have, much appreciated.